# Protect VBA code for Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Besides adding a password under Project Properties > Protection (Which I think is actually quite easy to hack), how can I prevent users from viewing / copying my code?

Comment: [*.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh133430.aspx)

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16757119/best-way-to-protect-excel-vba-code/16758219#16758219

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this is the good possibility: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa189867(v=office.10).aspx

> To provide the highest level of security for your VBA code, use
>   Microsoft Visual Basic version 6.0 to create a Component Object Model
>   (COM) add-in. Because the VBA code in a COM add-in is compiled as a
>   dynamic-link library (DLL), it can't be modified without access to the
>   source code used to originally create it. Application-specific add-ins
>   are not compiled; you must use the same protections as templates and
>   documents.