# How can I prevent users from viewing VB code in MS project but allow them to run the code through a custom UI?

Tags: vba, ms-project

I have a series of macros that I want end users to be able to execute via a custom U/I that is ready and working.  Is there a way that I can prevent users from having all features in the MS Project 'Macros' menu but still have them be able to use the custom U/I and macros as invoked from that U/I?

I have seen plenty of articles on how to disable macros, but I I simply want to block or hide he options in the 'Macros' but have VBA able to run via my custom U/I.

Comment: There is always a way to see the code. VBA is not secure by any means.

Comment: Just password protect it. If they have the skills to subvert that, then they have the skills to just write the VBA themselves. VBA isn't rocket science. You don't need extreme measures to protect it.

Comment: Protecting VBA code in Project is the same as in Excel; see [Best way to protect Excel VBA code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16757119/best-way-to-protect-excel-vba-code).